# Tkinter GUI App issue with webbrowser module

Tags: python, tkinter, python-webbrowser

I am trying to make a simple GUI app which open programs and websites using web browser python module but when try to search it does not open the web browser however it opens apps and can anyone help me out?code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import webbrowser
import os

def todo(TODO):
    try:
        if TODO== 'pycharm':
            os.startfile("C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\\bin\\pycharm64.exe")
        elif TODO== 'sublime':
            os.startfile("C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe")
        elif '.py'or '.txt' or '.csv' or '.ppt' in TODO:
            os.open('{}'.format(TODO,os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT))
            os.startfile('{}'.format(TODO))
        elif 'search' in TODO:
            url='http://google.com/search?q='+TODO.replace('search','')
            webbrowser.open(url)
        elif 'facebook' in TODO:
            webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
        elif 'instagram' in TODO:
            webbrowser.open('https://www.instagram.com/')
        else:
            pass
    except :
        pass

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('To-Do GUI')


entry = tk.Entry(root, font=40, width=35)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
entry.focus()

button = tk.Button(root, text="GO", font=40, command=lambda: todo(entry.get()))
button.grid(row=0 ,column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the `webbrowser` module at all, it's because of this line:

```
elif '.py' or '.txt' or '.csv' or '.ppt' in TODO:
```

which is always `True` and needs to be written. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
elif '.py' in TODO or '.txt' in TODO or '.csv' in  TODO or '.ppt' in TODO:
```

You can't see what's really wrong because you have a "bare" `except:` and `pass` to go along with the `try:`, which hides *all* errors including those you never thought of like syntax errors. (Actually there's yet another different problem you haven't yet encountered.)

To avoid this, at least during development and debugging, I suggest you change it to at least:

```
except Exception as exc:
    print('Exception occurred: {}'.format(exc))
    pass
```

or even better:

```
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    pass
```

so you'll get some clue about why it's not running like you expected.

**Update:**

Here's a little more advanced way of writing that `elif`:

```
elif any(ext in TODO for ext in ('.py', '.txt', '.csv', '.ppt')):
```